# How to use colspan in apex:pageBlockSection VF pages

Tags: visualforce

How can I align the same `Emp Department` fields with the `Employee` `pageBlockSection`? I have tried all sort of technics but no success

What I want is simple align with Employee pageblockSection.

Also I have tried in developer console and if I changed from colspan=2 to 4 then its align perfectly the way i wanted but I could not able to make using visualforce page.

[image]

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" title="Employee" columns="2" >

    <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.start_Date__c}"  />
    <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.Enrollment__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.end_Date__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.status__c}" />           

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Emp Department"   />
    <br/>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Emp Department" id="pbs2" columns="2"   >   
        <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.Type__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.Customer__c}"  />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>   

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: you want the "Emp Department" pageblocksection to be within the pageblocksection of "employee"?

Comment: can you try column ="1" for "emp department" pageblocksection?

Comment: @AnuragA: if i go with that route then,  I'm getting all the fields in Employee with one column which I do not want but I like to have column=2 with both Employee and emp department

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a pageBlockSection inside a pageBlockSection. This is what's screwing you up; the second section appears in the first section's left column when you do this. Furthermore, sectionHeader is really meant to be the thing at the top when you're looking at a record. Your code should probably look as follows:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" title="Employee" columns="2" >
        <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.start_Date__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.Enrollment__c}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.end_Date__c}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.status__c}" />           
    </apex:pageBlockSection> 
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Emp Department" id="pbs2" columns="2"   >   
        <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.Type__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.Customer__c}"  />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>   
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: I have used sectionHeader just to distinguishes with between two pageblockSection

Comment: @NickKahn When you include the "title" attribute, the page block section will do that for you automatically.

Comment: How can I have a row lines in the emp department pageblockSection? the background is white without any row lines as i have in the employee pageblockSection